# Minfy CSS and Javascript that includes @import url (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, minify, squishit

I have about 20 CSS files loading on my page, and I am looking for a tool to minify my CSS and JavaScript. I really like SquishIt, but it doesn't seem to handle css that is loaded via @import url. Since quite a few of my CSS files are loaded via @import, the output is not correct.

Is there a fix for this, or can someone recommended another tool that properly handles CSS imported via @import?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try calling the .ProcessImports method on css bundle setup?  I think it does what you want, see test case CanRenderCssFileWithImportStatement() in [this file](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Tests/CSSBundleTests.cs#L733-758)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Optimization if you are not using Asp.Net 4.5.
Install this Nuget package: Use http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Optimization/0.1 package.

How to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx

http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html